# Some mystery behavior while Sort List C#

Tags: c#

I need to sort my `List<FileObj>`. I need to do it according to the date that FileObj contains as a path

```
fileObj.fullPath = "C:\\Downloads\\2020_11_30_12_34\\myfilename.txt"
```

So, I need to substring a data from this path convert it and compare them. In order to do it I use such a method

```
filteredFiles.Sort((x, y) = >
{
    string firstPath = x.FullPath;
    string secondPath = y.FullPath;

    List<string> splitFirstPath = firstPath.Split(DELIMITER).ToList();
    List<string> splitSecondPath = secondPath.Split(DELIMITER).ToList();

    DateTime ? firstPathDate = null;

    foreach(string tmp in splitFirstPath)
    {
        firstPathDate = DateUtil.ConvertStringToDate(tmp, Constants.DATE_PATTERN);

        if (firstPathDate != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    DateTime ? secondPathDate = null;

    foreach(string tmp in splitSecondPath)
    {
        secondPathDate = DateUtil.ConvertStringToDate(tmp, Constants.DATE_PATTERN);

        if (secondPathDate != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    int result = (firstPathDate != null
        && secondPathDate != null
        && firstPathDate.Value != null
        && secondPathDate.Value != null) ? secondPathDate.Value.CompareTo(firstPathDate.Value) : -1;

    return result;
});
```

DELIMITER here is `\\` so I just try to convert each part of the path and if success I get a date if not I get null, then I compare them two at the end.

Problem is that along with expected paths like above - "C:\Downloads\2020_11_30_12_34\myfilename.txt" there are also a lot of other paths that even don't contains date in their path, like this "C:\Downloads\examplefolder\myfilename.txt"

Actually it should not be a problem because in case if I can't convert date I get null and compare result is `-1` it means that such files will be at the end of the list, right?

But mystery is - if I have in my origin list for example 10 such a "wrong" paths it is work as expected and they all went to the end of the list, BUT if I have 20 such a "wrong" paths this method give me here `Sort((x, y)` x - as a null ref obj.

How it could be possible? I know exactly that this list `filteredFiles` doesn't contain any null objects I see it when debug I see that input has all objects without any null.

From where I get this mystery null object on 20th iteration?

**P.S.** I know that I can just check on null, but I am interested how does it appear there in list?

**EDIT**

Eventually I fixed it this way

```
        try
        {
            contentFromAllAgents.Sort((x, y) =>
            {
                string firstPath = x?.FullPath;
                string secondPath = y?.FullPath;

                List<string> splitFirstPath = firstPath?.Split(DELIMITER)?.ToList();
                List<string> splitSecondPath = secondPath?.Split(DELIMITER)?.ToList();

                DateTime? firstPathDate = null;

                foreach (string tmp in splitFirstPath ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
                {
                    firstPathDate = DateUtil.ConvertStringToDate(tmp, Constants.DATE_PATTERN);

                    if (firstPathDate != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                DateTime? secondPathDate = null;

                foreach (string tmp in splitSecondPath ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
                {
                    secondPathDate = DateUtil.ConvertStringToDate(tmp, Constants.DATE_PATTERN);

                    if (secondPathDate != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (firstPathDate == null)
                {
                    firstPathDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                }

                if (secondPathDate == null)
                {
                    secondPathDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                }

                int result = (firstPathDate != null
                            && secondPathDate != null
                            && firstPathDate.Value != null
                            && secondPathDate.Value != null) ? secondPathDate.Value.CompareTo(firstPathDate.Value) : -1;

                return result;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error while sorting :: {e}");
        }
```

I have provided default values for those who null and in addition added `try/catch` in case if I'll have any other errors, because it my case it was not easy to find out that issue in sorting as it doesn't through any errors(I don't know why) just was in stuck.

Comment: You're violating many requirements of the `Compare<T>` delegate - for instance, if a `FileObj` doesn't contain a date then it *doesn't return 0 when compared with itself*. Also, (A,B) and (B,A) shouldn't both be capable of returning -1.

Comment: You can use linq's where to filter out ones that don't contain valid paths. Also Instead of using nulls. I'd use probably the epoch as the default value and simply subtract one from the other and return the result. That way you return <= -1 , 0, and >= 1

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok, so in this case I see it will be more appropriate to provide default value for those who don't have a date(like John mentioned). And then I'll get the right behavior

Comment: @John seems like a good idea to provide default values for those who null, but filter by `where` am not sure as anyway at the end I need to get an entire list.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko using default values should fix your issue then as long as the date you use as the default value is lower than anything you would get from the folder names.